# JPA identifier of an instance of Object was altered from ObjectPK to ObjectPK

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have tables in DB: A, B, D

Relationship between A and B are OneToMany.
Relationship between B and D are OneToMany.
I want to copy an item of A from a to a'

**Table A:** Primary key is id.

```
id      description
a       aaa
b       bbb
c       ccc
```

**Table B:**  Primary key is id and id_A.

```
id      id_A      description
1       a         xyz
2       a         x'y'z'
```

**Table D:**  Primary key is id, id_A, id_B.

```
id      id_A      id_B      description
1       a         1         xyz
2       a         2         x'y'z'
```

When copy item "a" in A table, two items in B has id is 1 and 2 must be copied.
And DB I wish after copying is following:

**Table A:**

```
id      description
a       aaa
b       bbb
c       ccc
a'      aaa
```

**Table B:**

```
id      id_A      description
1       a         xyz
2       a         x'y'z'
1       a'        xyz
2       a'        x'y'z'
```

**Table D:**

```
id      id_A      id_B      description
1       a         1         xyz
2       a         2         x'y'z'
1       a'        1         xyz
2       a'        2         x'y'z'
```

And this is my code for Dao:

```
public void copy(A a', String id_A) throws Exception {
        EntityManager em = JPA.em();
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Consts.DEFAULT_PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        // insert new A with a'
        insert(a');

        // insert B for A
        BDao Bdao = new BDao();
        DDao Ddao = new DDao();
        List<B> listB = dao.findByAId(id_A);
        List<D> listD = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listB.size(); i++) {            
            BPK id = new BPK();
            id.setId_A(id_A);
            B newB = listB.get(i);
            newB.setId(id);
            Bdao.insert(newB);
            if (((i + 1) % listB.size()) == 0) {
                em.flush();
                em.clear();
            }

            // insert D
            listD = Ddao.getById(id_A, newB.getId().getId_B());
            for (int j = 0; j < listD.size(); j++) {
                D newD = listD.get(i);
                newD.setId().setId_A(id_A);
                newD.setId().setId_B(newB.getId().getId_B());
                Ddao.insert(newD);
                if (((j + 1) % listD.size()) == 0) {
                    em.flush();
                    em.clear();
                }
            }
        }

        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

But when I run, errors happened:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an B was altered from BPK@7fa6cf87 to BPK@62310b05
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
    at jp.co.cacco.OPLUX.api.daos.JudgingRuleDao.findByAuthoriModelId(JudgingRuleDao.java:281)
    at jp.co.cacco.OPLUX.api.daos.AuthoriModelDao.copyAuthoriModel(AuthoriModelDao.java:241)
    at jp.co.cacco.OPLUX.api.services.AuthoriModelDetailService.copyAuthoriModel(AuthoriModelDetailService.java:252)
    at jp.co.cacco.OPLUX.manager.controllers.AuthoriModelDetailController.submit(AuthoriModelDetailController.java:126)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$115$$anonfun$apply$115.apply(routes_routing.scala:2044)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$115$$anonfun$apply$115.apply(routes_routing.scala:2044)
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(Router.scala:264)
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$15$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:255)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:55)
    at play.GlobalSettings$1.call(GlobalSettings.java:67)
    at play.mvc.Security$AuthenticatedAction.call(Security.java:44)
    at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction$1.apply(TransactionalAction.java:23)
    at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction$1.apply(TransactionalAction.java:21)
    at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransactionAsync(JPA.java:180)
    at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction.call(TransactionalAction.java:18)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$11.apply(JavaAction.scala:82)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$11.apply(JavaAction.scala:82)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:46)
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:492)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$class.apply(JavaAction.scala:82)
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$15$$anon$1.apply(Router.scala:252)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:129)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:128)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:128)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:121)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:483)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:483)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:519)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:519)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:496)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:496)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of B was altered from BPK@7fa6cf87 to BPK@62310b05
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1191)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1257)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    ... 49 more
```

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: IDs are immutable. You may not change their value. Don't modify the IDs of existing Ds. Create copies of Ds, and set the ID of the copies.

Comment: I modified code. But it still occurs above error.

Comment: You're doing the same mistake with B.